# QT - Check if QT app is the app in focus

Tags: c++, qt

Here is what I want to do :

Check if my Qt app on windows is an app on the front or minimized.
If its minimized then draw the users attention by making it blink.

Now  how can i detect if the app is minimized or on the background ?

Comment: There's no such thing as an app being "minimized" or "visible."  The word you're looking for is window, not app.  Try checking the QWindow documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#isActiveWindow-prop

then, you can call `QWidget::activateWindow()`.

Looking at the notes:

> if you are calling this when the application is not currently the active one then it will not make it the active window. It will change the color of the taskbar entry to indicate that the window has changed in some way.

This sounds exactly like this blink effect you are trying to achieve.

(Links are for Qt5, but this already exists in Qt4: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#activateWindow)